# After binarizing a column of my data-set using sklearn the result is not correct. where is the code wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I pre-processing a data-set. I binarized one of the columns. after binarization I think the values are incorrect. the data has 303 observations(rows) and 14 features(columns).and the column i am binarizing is the last column.

here is a part of my code-

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    #importing the dataset
    header_names = ['age','sex','cp','trestbps','chol','fbs','restecg','thalach','exang','oldpeak','slope','ca','thal','num']
    dataset = pd.read_csv('E:/HCU proj doc/EHR dataset/cleveland_data.csv', names= header_names)


    array = dataset.values

    # binarize num
    from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer
    x = array[:,13:]
    binarize = Binarizer(threshold=0.0).fit(x)
    transform_binarize = binarize.transform(x)

    array[:,13:]=transform_binarize
    print(transform_binarize)
```

here is what the original data column look like-

```
     0,2,1,0,0.........1,0,3,1,1,2
```

and here is the output of the above code-

```
         [[0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]]
```

I think the last ones are incorrect. I dont understand why is that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am correct in assuming that this is the heart disease dataset taken from [this UCI repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease) and the csv file is [this one](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data), then in that case these are correct values for binarizer. The original data column that you are using has a `0` in the final row, I think you missed that, try this code

```
for idx in range(0,len(x)):
    print idx,x[idx],transform_binarize[idx]
```

**Output**

```
278 [1L] [1.]
279 [0L] [0.]
280 [2L] [1.]
281 [0L] [0.]
282 [3L] [1.]
283 [0L] [0.]
284 [2L] [1.]
285 [4L] [1.]
286 [2L] [1.]
287 [0L] [0.]
288 [0L] [0.]
289 [0L] [0.]
290 [1L] [1.]
291 [0L] [0.]
292 [2L] [1.]
293 [2L] [1.]
294 [1L] [1.]
295 [0L] [0.]
296 [3L] [1.]
297 [1L] [1.]
298 [1L] [1.]
299 [2L] [1.]
300 [3L] [1.]
301 [1L] [1.]
302 [0L] [0.]     #<--- I think you missed this row while reading your dataset
```

If you try this code then you will that the binarizer is working exactly as it should be.

Comment: This answer is based on specific knowledge of the dataset, and does not indicate where in OP's code there is a specific problem -- which is the main request of the question ("Where is the code wrong?"). The application of this answer is too limited to be useful to future readers.